# Image visualization is giving error

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to map my final image but its showing error as Layer 2: Tile error: Number of pixels requested from Image.load exceeds the maximum allowed (2^31). Tile error: Reprojection output too large (27649x18433 pixels).
I'm not sure why its not visualizing the image on gee map layout. This is the code I'm using

```
// Map.centerObject(geometry);
// Define visualization parameters
var visParams_cover = {
  min: -30, // set the minimum value for the color scale
  max: 0, // set the maximum value for the color scale
  gamma: 1.5, // set the gamma value for the color scale
  opacity: 0.45 // set the opacity to 65%
};


Map.addLayer(s1_dsc_cover.clip(geometry), visParams_cover, 'Sentinel-1 Descending Coverage');

var wrapper = require('users/adugnagirma/gee_s1_ard:wrapper');
var helper = require('users/adugnagirma/gee_s1_ard:utilities');

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// DEFINE PARAMETERS
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//


var parameter = {//1. Data Selection
              START_DATE: "2016-01-01",
              STOP_DATE: "2022-12-31",
              POLARIZATION:'VVVH',
              ORBIT : 'DESCENDING',
              GEOMETRY: geometry, //Uncomment if providing coordinates
              //2. Additional Border noise correction
              APPLY_ADDITIONAL_BORDER_NOISE_CORRECTION: true,
              //3.Speckle filter
              APPLY_SPECKLE_FILTERING: false,
              SPECKLE_FILTER_FRAMEWORK: 'MULTI',
              SPECKLE_FILTER: 'BOXCAR',
              SPECKLE_FILTER_KERNEL_SIZE: 15,
              SPECKLE_FILTER_NR_OF_IMAGES: 10,
              //4. Radiometric terrain false
              APPLY_TERRAIN_FLATTENING: true,
              DEM: ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003'),
              TERRAIN_FLATTENING_MODEL: 'VOLUME',
              TERRAIN_FLATTENING_ADDITIONAL_LAYOVER_SHADOW_BUFFER: 0,
              //5. Output
              FORMAT : 'DB',
              CLIP_TO_ROI: false,
              SAVE_ASSETS: false
}
print.parameter
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// DO THE JOB
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
      

//Preprocess the S1 collection
var s1_preprocces = wrapper.s1_preproc(parameter);

var s1 = s1_preprocces[0]
s1_preprocces = s1_preprocces[1]

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// VISUALIZE
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//

//Visulaization of the first image in the collection in RGB for VV, VH, images
var visparam = {}
if (parameter.POLARIZATION=='VVVH'){
     if (parameter.FORMAT=='DB'){
    var s1_preprocces_view = s1_preprocces.map(helper.add_ratio_lin).map(helper.lin_to_db2);
    var s1_view = s1.map(helper.add_ratio_lin).map(helper.lin_to_db2);
    visparam = {bands:['VV','VH','VVVH_ratio'],min: [-20, -25, 1],max: [0, -5, 15]}
    }
    else {
    var s1_preprocces_view = s1_preprocces.map(helper.add_ratio_lin);
    var s1_view = s1.map(helper.add_ratio_lin);
    visparam = {bands:['VV','VH','VVVH_ratio'], min: [0.01, 0.0032, 1.25],max: [1, 0.31, 31.62]}
    }
}
else {
    if (parameter.FORMAT=='DB') {
    s1_preprocces_view = s1_preprocces.map(helper.lin_to_db);
    s1_view = s1.map(helper.lin_to_db);
    visparam = {bands:[parameter.POLARIZATION],min: -25,max: 0}   
    }
    else {
    s1_preprocces_view = s1_preprocces;
    s1_view = s1;
    visparam = {bands:[parameter.POLARIZATION],min: 0,max: 0.2}
    }
}


// Load the image collection
var imageCollection = s1_preprocces_view
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-03-12', '2018-03-16').not());

// Define the deforestation mask and clip to geometry
var deforestationMask = hansen.select('loss').gt(0)
  .rename('deforestationMask')
  .clip(geometry);

// Define the slope mask with a threshold of 15 degrees and clip to geometry
var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(elevationdata.select('elevation'));
var slopeMask = slope.lt(15)
  .rename('slopeMask')
  .clip(geometry);

// Define the forest mask at 30% tree cover and clip to geometry
var forestMask = hansen.select('treecover2000').gte(30)
  .rename('forestMask')
  .clip(geometry);

var thresholdMask = hansen.select('treecover2000')
  .reduceResolution({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    maxPixels: 65535 
  })
  .reproject({
    crs: hansen.projection(),
    scale: 1000
  })
  .int()
  .gte(5)
  .rename('thresholdMask')
  .clip(geometry);

// Create the combined mask and clip to geometry
var combinedMask = forestMask
  .updateMask(deforestationMask.not())
  .updateMask(slopeMask)
  .updateMask(thresholdMask)
  .where(forestMask.neq(1), ee.Image().byte().updateMask(forestMask.eq(0)))
  .clip(geometry);

// Define a function to filter to the dominant orbit using a sliding window approach
var filterToDominantOrbit = function(image) {
  // Add the relative orbit band to the image
  var relativeOrbitBand = ee.Image.constant(image.get('relativeOrbitNumber_start')).rename('relativeOrbit');
  image = image.addBands(relativeOrbitBand);

  // Define the window size
  var windowSize = 3;

  // Define the window
  var kernel = ee.Kernel.square({
    radius: windowSize,
    units: 'pixels'
  });

  // Compute the mode of the relative orbit band within the window
  var dominantOrbit = relativeOrbitBand.reduceNeighborhood({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mode(),
    kernel: kernel
  }).rename('dominantOrbit');

  // Filter the image to pixels where the relative orbit equals the dominant orbit
  var filteredImage = image.updateMask(relativeOrbitBand.eq(dominantOrbit));

  return filteredImage;
};

// Apply the combined mask to the image collection
var ARimageCollection = imageCollection
  .map(function(image) {
    var angle = image.select('angle');
    var maskedImage = image.updateMask(angle.gte(30.9).and(angle.lt(45.1))).updateMask(combinedMask);
    return maskedImage;
  })
  .map(filterToDominantOrbit);

// Select the minimum and maximum values of VV from the filtered collection
var minMaxVV = ARimageCollection.select(['VV']).reduce(ee.Reducer.minMax());
var minVV = minMaxVV.select('VV_min');
var maxVV = minMaxVV.select('VV_max');

// Subtract the minimum value from the maximum value and get an output image
var VV_range = maxVV.subtract(minVV);

// Create an image where each pixel has the computed minVV value
var minVV_img = ee.Image().expression('minVV', {'minVV': minVV}).rename('minVV');

// Create an image where each pixel has the computed maxVV value
var maxVV_img = ee.Image().expression('maxVV', {'maxVV': maxVV}).rename('maxVV');

// Create an image where each pixel has the computed VV_range value
var VV_range_img = ee.Image().expression('VV_range', {'VV_range': VV_range}).rename('VV_range');

// Add the computed values as separate layers to the map
//Map.addLayer(minVV_img, {min: -25, max: 0}, 'Minimum VV');
//Map.addLayer(maxVV_img, {min: -25, max: 0}, 'Maximum VV');
//Map.addLayer(VV_range_img, {min: 0, max: 10}, 'VV Range');

// Select the minimum and maximum values of VH from the filtered collection
var minMaxVH = ARimageCollection.select(['VH']).reduce(ee.Reducer.minMax());
var minVH = minMaxVH.select('VH_min');
var maxVH = minMaxVH.select('VH_max');

// Subtract the minimum value from the maximum value and get an output image
var VH_range = maxVH.subtract(minVH);

// Create an image where each pixel has the computed minVH value
var minVH_img = ee.Image().expression('minVH', {'minVH': minVH}).rename('minVH');

// Create an image where each pixel has the computed maxVH value
var maxVH_img = ee.Image().expression('maxVH', {'maxVH': maxVH}).rename('maxVH');

// Create an image where each pixel has the computed VH_range value
var VH_range_img = ee.Image().expression('VH_range', {'VH_range': VH_range}).rename('VH_range');

// Add the computed values as separate layers to the map
//Map.addLayer(minVH_img, {min: -25, max: 0}, 'Minimum VH');
//Map.addLayer(maxVH_img, {min: -25, max: 0}, 'Maximum VH');
//Map.addLayer(VH_range_img, {min: 0, max: 10}, 'VH Range');


// Compute the mean and standard deviation for VV and VH bands
var VV_mean = ARimageCollection.select('VV').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());
var VH_mean = ARimageCollection.select('VH').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());
var VV_stdDev = ARimageCollection.select('VV').reduce(ee.Reducer.stdDev());
var VH_stdDev = ARimageCollection.select('VH').reduce(ee.Reducer.stdDev());

// Combine the bands into a single image
var finalImage = ee.Image.cat(VV_mean, VH_mean, VV_stdDev, VH_stdDev, VV_range_img, VH_range_img);

// Rename the bands to include the metric name and polarization
finalImage = finalImage.rename([
    'VV_mean', 'VH_mean', 'VV_stdDev', 'VH_stdDev', 'VV_range_img', 'VH_range_img'
]);
print(finalImage)
Map.addLayer(finalImage.clip(geometry))
```

this is code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/beaa2dc69397b6a63be77e17c65d6a74